# ASP.MVC client side validation does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, client-side, unobtrusive-validation

I am trying to validate user input on login page. 
I have my `User mode` with:

- string UserName
- string Password

I decided to extend my DB model with partial class:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(User))]
public partial class User : IUser
{

}

public interface IUser
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Login is required")]
    string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
    string Password { get; set; }
}
```

And my `view`:

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
   {
      @Html.ValidationSummary(true)      
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, new { size = 30, @placeholder = "Login",    
      @class = "credential" })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
      @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { size = 30, @placeholder = 
   "Password",    @class = "credential" })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
   }
```

Instead of client validation, it makes postback and crashes on null values in model.

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706174/mvc3-client-side-validation-not-working) I added

```
HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = true;
HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = true;
```

to the top of view, made sure that scripts are loaded:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"></script>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you any error in web browser?

Comment: Dont have any errors, It crashes in `Model.Designer.cs` and than does not pass through `ModelState.IsValid`

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/275056/Custom-Client-Side-Validation-in-ASP-NET-MVC3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be related to the fact that you have the validation on the interface property rather than the class property.

Check the DOM element.  It should look like this for the user name:

```
<input class="credential" data-val="true" data-val-required="Login is required" id="UserName" name="UserName" placeholder="Login" size="30" type="text" value="">
```

Note the data-val & data-val-required attributes.  These are used by the js validation logic.

When I try using your interface property validation, these are missing.

Maybe you should use a viewmodel for this rather than the model?  That way you can tailor it to the view requirements.

**Edit**

Actually, just make your @model declaration in the razor view to reference IUser rather than User.

```
@model IUser
```

Comment: With model it works fine on other views, it just seems logical to add validation via interface rather than creating view model.

My inputs dont have `data-val` and `data-val-required`, so yeah, you are right) Thanks

Have you tried to provide interfaces validation (except my interface)? Maybe I am missing something on this

Comment: No I never use interface validation.  The reason is that I never use models on the view.  I use a ViewModel.  It makes more sense to me to have the ViewModel approach as we can then introduce view logic onto it - so validation, collections that contain items for dropdowns, etc.  These wouldn't really be present on the model as it is more concerned with business logic.