# Showing a success validation message in ASP.Net MVC from server side validation

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

If my server side validation passes I want to show a message that I pass back from the server to the client. Error messages are possible (defined as an attribute on the property in ASP.Net MVC), can I show a success message? Maybe I can tap into the JQuery validate plugin to do this??

ex. I do a lookup from of the location to get a city I want to pass back the city as a string to display it as a validation success message.

Here is my code.

```
    [Required()]
    [MaxLength(5)]
    [MinLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Can't find location")]
    [Display(Name = "Zip code")]
    [Remote("CheckLocation", "Account", AreaReference.UseCurrent, ErrorMessage = "Invalid zipcode")]
    public string Location { get; set; }


    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public JsonResult CheckLocation(int Location)
    {
        var city = getLocation(Location);
        if (city != null)
        {
            // pass the city back with the JSon object, but how do I display it???
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

***EDIT*** here is what I tried. I'm using jQuery Validate now instead of remote attributes on my `c#` property. This works fine but how do I define a success property here in remote and pass that success message to the validation messsage? and then change the color to green instead of red?

```js
$('#Location').rules("add", {
  required: true,
  minlength: 5,
  maxlength: 5,
  messages: {
    required: "Required input",
    minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please, {0} characters are necessary"),
    maxlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please, {0} characters are necessary")
  },
  remote: {
    url: "CheckLocation",
    type: "post",
    data: {
      Location: function() {
        return $('#Location').val();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

***EDIT 2***
I really want to show a succes message coming from the server (ex. shoing the city when a zip is entered), so I think I can use a success callback on the remote call and in the callback manipulate the message color and make the element valid. I think validate sets it to false if there is a string in the JSon response?

something like this.

```
        [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public JsonResult CheckLocation(int Location)
    {
        var city = getLocation(Location);
        if (city != null)
        {
            return Json(city); // this will be text like "London"
        }
        return Json(false);
    }
```

```js
$('#Location').rules("add", {
  required: true,
  //minlength: 5,
  maxlength: 5,
  messages: {
    required: "Required input",
    minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please, {0} characters are necessary"),
    maxlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please, {0} characters are necessary")
  },
  remote: {
    url: "CheckLocation",
    type: "post",
    data: {
      Location: function() {
        return $('#Location').val();
      }
    },
    success: function(data) {
      // change the color from red to green for the message
      // make the invalid element valid so it passes submition
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: check this one it should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28366314/mvc5-data-annotations-client-side-validation-not-happening

Comment: @user1186050 Why can you not use a label for the error or sucess message, give it an id and then set the value in the jquery depending on return value?

Comment: I guess I could, but isn't there some JQuery validate stuff going on under the hood? I want to show all the validate error messages. and I want to make sure the form has invalid fields before I try and submit

Comment: what I'm basically trying to accomplish is to emulate www.okcupid.com register page where you enter in a zip and if the zip code is found is says "ah, San Francisco!" or "location not found"

Comment: Using onfocusout event and Ajax will validate before you submit

Comment: If you feel my answer is correct please select it as answer and upvote

Comment: I think I might havea better solution. check my 2nd edit

Comment: Please only use the "code snippet" feature for HTML/JavaScript/CSS code that can be run within the window on this page.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[The `success` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#success) of the `.validate()` method is used for controlling the message element when validation passes.  By default, the error message is hidden when validation passes.  When using `success`, you can modify this behavior and show an icon, message, etc. when validation passes.  However, this option does not retrieve messages from your server.

jQuery Validate is client-side code, and there is only one built-in method that will take a response from the server and that is the [`remote`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/) method.  However, the issue here is that you can only pass a `true` to pass validation, a `false` to fail validation... and if you pass a string, it's converted into an *error* message and validation *fails*.

AFAIK, **there is no built-in method for doing what you want**.  Perhaps you can write a custom `success` function that uses `.ajax()` to retrieve a message from your server.

---

**Summary**:

1. the plugin does not typically show messages on success. The `success` option is a way to force it to show messages.  However, the issue with this is that you cannot pass a value into this option.  It's just a way to control the error message object when the field is valid.
2. the plugin does not typically communicate with the server except for the `remote` method.  The issue with this is that you can only pass `true` to pass validation.  If you pass a string, validation will fail (*and the string becomes the validation error message*).

---

**EDIT in response to OP:**

> but how do I define a success property here in remote and pass that success message to the validation messsage?

**You can only use [the `success` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#success) to properly manipulate the error element**.  However, I don't think you'll be able to achieve the stated objective since there does not seem to be a way to pass the field's value into the `success` option.  Otherwise, you could use `.ajax()` within `success` to retrieve your message.

> and then change the color to green instead of red?

This is done automatically by defining your CSS properties for the `valid` and `error` classes.  You can also apply custom classes using `.addClass()` within the `success` option.

**IMO, your entire goal cannot be achieved using the jQuery Validate plugin.  However, you should thoroughly review [the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org) to be sure for yourself.**

---

> I think validate sets it to false if there is a string in the JSon response?

Yes, exactly as already stated in my answer.  If the server response is *anything* other than `true`, the validation is set to fail.

Comment: won't the remote call in validate take a success property that I can use to pass a message back to the client side? Then couldn't I just display it in the validation message and color it green or something?

Comment: @user1186050 You said you wanted to display city

Comment: @user1186050, If the `remote` call gets *anything* other than `"true"`, the field is flagged as "invalid".

Comment: what I want to show is the city, right. If I pass in a zipcode and a city is found I want to display the city in the validation message ex. "you found city San Francisco!", this would be after passing in "94102", other wise the error message is displayed saying something like "city not found"

Comment: @user1186050 so did you try the method I told you it would exactly do what you want

Comment: @user1186050, as explained, 1.  the plugin does not typically show messages on success.  The `success` option is a way to force it to show messages.  2.  the plugin does not typically communicate with the server except for the `remote` method.

Comment: I'll post what I have above, butI'm not sure about the success message.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is this

Use ajax to call a custom action method instead of remote data annotation

```
    var url = "/MyController/CheckLocation/";

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: { zipcode: _zipcode },
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json"
}).done(function (obgcity) {

     //If objcity is null then display error else display city
    }
});
```

Comment: How would this get integrated into the jQuery Validate plugin?

Comment: @Sparky He can use this in his view file or add it to scripts and then add a bundle for this script to his view file

Comment: @Sparky And by plugin if you mean To the jquery script file then he can add this code to the script file

Comment: @Sparky He can then use the event onfocusout event to call a javascript function containing this ajax code

Answer (score 0):

I wish code below helps you.

```
public ActionResult CheckLocation(int Location)
    {
        var city = getLocation(Location);
        if (city != null)
        {
            // city is string type, example: string city="Mumbai";
            return Json(new {Status=true, City = city}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return Json(new { Status=false, City=""}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Now as Sparky has mentioned in message above give call to your action or method using ajax and write a custom success function

```
 var locationId = 20;
 $.ajax({
    url: "MyController/CheckLocation",
    data: { Location: locationId},
    cache: false,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
             if(data.Status == true)
             {
                 alert(data.City); 
                // instead of alert you can create custom message alert box,
                // or if you want to display city name or whatever message
                // you can try $("#cityId").Html("<p>this is city</p>");   
             }        
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert("Ajax Failed!!!");
     }
});
```